# iAd does not show up in my apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, iad, banner

I have an app for iPhone, and one for iPad. Both of them uses iAd and it worked before.
But now iAd never loads in them! I just released the one for iPhone, so I'm in a hurry!

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting delegate callbacks from your iAd instance?

Comment: Also: Your iAds worked before what exactly? Before you posted here? Before iOS 6 arrived? Before your Birthday?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of info. 
When the code is not changed, probably a fault in iTunes connect with the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Apple only has so many ads to give out. When the iAd Banner View is on screen it requests an ad but one is not always available to fill it.
Check in iTunes Connect if you look at your iAd Network data you will get an average fill rate along with other info.